# ./"ProgramName" doesnt work at ubuntu server (Amazon EC2)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I am currently trying to get my server (C#) running on an Ubuntu server. The Ubuntu server is hosted with Amazon EC2.
I have developed the server on my Windows PC. Here everything works without problems.
I have now proceeded as follows:

- Visual Studio right click on my project
- Clicked on Publish
- Target runtime: Linux-x64
- copied everything with WinScp to the Ubuntu server.

If I now want to start the file in the publish folder with "sudo ./ProgramName" I only get an error message: "command not found".

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is sudo installed on EC2 cloud?

Comment: "Is sudo installed on EC2 cloud?" yes

Comment: "Have you confirmed you have both ..." I dont have a GUI :( with ls -l it shows me my program but it is not highlighted in green. I can try it in a VM

Comment: oh lol, i found out what the problem is. chmod u+x "ProgramName" Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

chmod u+x "ProgramName"

:)